# matplotlib overlaps line-plots so I get a thick line - it also overlaps x-axis text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to get some matplotlib exercises done and if I use a python list to plot, it works fine, when I use a data frame from an excel, I get the figure, **but overlapped with 'line' and 'area'**, *however, it works with 'bar'*

here is the working code

```
    import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

# I use some excel with over 100 rows and 40 columns with geographical data
df_can = pd.read_excel(
    'https://url-to-excel/data.xlsx' ,
    sheet_name='Second Tab',
    skiprows=range(20),
    skipfooter=2
    )

# rename some columns so that they can be easily understood
df_can.rename(columns={'OdName':'Country', 'AreaName':'Continent', 'RegName':'Region'}, inplace=True)
renamed_columns = df_can.columns

# set  the 'Country' column as the index using set_index() method
index_country = df_can.set_index('Country', inplace=True)

# convert years from INT to STR
df_can.columns = list(map(str, df_can.columns))

# let's declare a variable to  call upon the full range of years
years = list(map(str, range(1985, 2014)))
print(type(years))

# Plotting in pandas

# First, we will extract the data series for Argentina
# passing in years 1980 - 2013 to exclude the 'total' column
argentina = df_can.loc['Argentina', years]

# Next, we'll plot a line plot appending .plot() to the argentina dataframe
argentina.plot()

"""
pandas automatically populated the x-axis with the index values (years)
and the y-axis with the column values (population)
"""
# let's change the index values of argentina to type integer for plotting
argentina.index = argentina.index.map(int)
# if I use 'line' or 'area' it overlaps showing just a thick line to the left
argentina.plot(kind=**'bar'**, color='red', grid=False)

plt.title('Inmigracion desde Argentina')
plt.ylabel('Numero de inmigrantes')
plt.xlabel('Años')
plt.text(1995, 1750, 'Pico Maximo') # this does not show??

plt.show()
```

that gives us this nice image

[image]

If I replace 'bar' with 'line' or 'area'

```
argentina.plot(kind='bar', color='red', grid=False)# works ok

argentina.plot(kind='line', color='red', grid=False) # overlaps to the left and to the right.
```

I get This

[image]

***strong text***

So, how can I make that matplotlib auto-separate years (like it does with the first example; bars) but using line or area?

AND that this line

```
plt.text(1995, 1750, 'Pico Maximo') # this does not show??
```

shows in the image? It should appear at year 1995 X axis and at 1750 height at Y axis

Here the [link to excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187u9jurG4iYa3Vu0xi-oA4pDQ3WsnjVDq5c9BxhMLSY/edit) I am using, it is a UN immigration sheet, I use sheet number 2 so you have to

```
    sheet_name='Canada by Citizenship',
    skiprows=range(20),
    skipfooter=2
```

to get info from that sheet ('Argentina' or any country you like)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you maybe provide some data to run checks?

Comment: Actually, the text "Pico Maximo" appears in the top right corner of the second picture. However, if yo want to make sure the text apprears in the pic, you should directly use the `Axes` object that the pandas' `plot` returns, e.g.:  `ax = argentina.plot(kind='bar');  ax.text(1995, 1750, 'Pico Maximo')`

Comment: Hi, here the link to the excel from UN I am using

Comment: Hi,  YashvanderBamel , I edited the original questions so you have a link to the excel I am using to get any data you need